# Does an object rolling down a slope have more momentum than a object in free fall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, acceleration

Physics newbie here. I am trying to figure out in which of the following scenarios would the object end up further from the starting point:

Will a car that veers off a road that has a vertical cliff on its side end up further from the road than a car that veers off a road which has a slope the same height as the cliff but covers a longer distance?

Assuming the car immediately starts rolling down the slope and does not enter into a free fall landing some distance down the slope.

Answer (score 2):

Your question and your title are different.  Understanding that difference may help!

We'll start with the question, because it has an easy thought experiment available.  Start with the car moving *very* slow.  Maybe it ran out of gas and someone is pushing it.  In the first case, it is pushed off of the cliff.  In the second, someone has set up a smooth ramp for it.  Which goes further?

The answer should intuitively be the car on the ramp.  The car going off the cliff should fall almost straight down (into a pile of flaming wreckage).  The car going down the smooth ramp will drive much further.  We can even say that's because it's able to use the acceleration of gravity to accelerate it to the side.

If you get into the Newtonian physics of this, the key is that you have a normal force applied by the ramp.  Because that ramp is not perfectly horizontal (i.e. it's a ramp, not a floor), there's some component of its force going horizontally.  That force is going to accelerate the car horizontally.  Without doing any equations, we can see that both cars hit the same vertical position at the end, but the ramp car goes further horizontally, so it *must* cover a longer distance, by necessity.

As for momentum, that's a different story.  If we make some simplifying assumptions, like replacing your car with a spherical cow (a traditional humorous way of saying that we're ignoring things like friction), we will find that they have the same momentum at the end.  Why?  Potential energy is the easiest explanation.  In this simplified setup, the only forms of energy are gravitational potential energy (because the car is at some altitude) and kinetic energy (because the car is moving forward).  Both cars start with the same kinetic energy, and they lose the same amount of potential energy during the fall (both fall the same vertical height), so both cars must have the same kinetic energy at the bottom.

Kinetic energy is proportional to the square of the velocity ($KE=\frac 1 2 m v^2$, to be precise).  If their kinetic energies are the same at the bottom, then their velocities must be the same.  And since momentum is proportional to velocity ($P=mv$), their momentums must be the same as well.

So what gives?  How do they have the same momentum, but one traveled further?  It turns out there's no paradox there.  The car on the ramp took *longer* to reach the bottom.  The time spent is longer.  Since the distance traveled is a function of time, the car on the ramp can have traveled further, even if the velocities end up the same.

We also experience this intuitively moving very heavy objects on wheels.  Getting the object moving is very difficult.  It takes a lot of effort to get it moving fast.  However, you can get it moving slow, and just keep moving for long periods of time to get to your location.

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation! You really went above and beyond